# (yet another) "Unbound module" error

Tags: ocaml

The line

```
open Uutf
```

in my file `mymod.ml` is causing the error shown below:

```
% corebuild -quiet test.native
+ ocamlfind ocamlopt -c -w A-4-33-40-41-42-43-34-44 -strict-sequence -g -annot -bin-annot -short-paths -thread -syntax camlp4o -package bin_prot.syntax -package sexplib.syntax,comparelib.syntax,fieldslib.syntax,variantslib.syntax -package core -o mymod.cmx mymod.ml
File "mymod.ml", line 2, characters 5-9:
Error: Unbound module Uutf
```

I've previously installed `Uutf` with

```
% opam install uutf
```

What else is one supposed to do after running the `opam install` command above?

PS: I have read several SE threads on OCaml "Unbounded module" errors, including

[Ocaml unbound module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310469/ocaml-unbound-module)
[Error: Unbound module ... in Ocaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488087/error-unbound-module-in-ocaml)
[ocaml toplevel throws error unbounded module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689385/ocaml-toplevel-throws-error-unbounded-module)
[Ocaml and Opam: unbound module Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645634/ocaml-and-opam-unbound-module-core)

...but none have answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use

```
corebuild -package uutf test.native
```

This will automatically (using `ocamlfind`) find the dependend package and add all the needed flags.

You can query ocamlfind database with `ocamlfind list` shell comand, to see what libraries are available. It is very handy if you're unsure about the library name.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you use corebuild, i assume it's [that script](https://github.com/janestreet/core/blob/master/corebuild) given the display.

You should try adding `-lib uutf` in your command line so that your call to ocamlbuild knows it should link to it.

Comment: Thanks, but that one didn't work.  Adding `-package uutf` did, though.